# Dependency injection and Scala's Traits

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Do any of the Scala dependency injection allow to inject mixins?

As an example, consider the following traits:

```
trait MyService extends TraitA with TraitB
```

Here, `TraitA` and `TraitB` are completely abstract traits (i.e. interfaces). In other words, in order to have a concrete implementation of MyService, I need to mix in concrete implementations of `TraitA`, `TraitB` respectively.

In pseudo-code, I want to create a concrete module like so:

```
bind TraitA to TraitALike
bind TraitB to TraitBLike
concreteModule = resolve MyService
```

Where `TraitALike`, `TraitBLike`are concrete implementations of the abstract traits.

concrete module should now be an instance of `MyService extends TraitALike with TraitBLike`.

Do any dependency injection frameworks allow for injected mixins in this fashion in Scala?

Answer (score 0):

From all I know there is no such a framework at the moment.

You request is very specific and you would need a some kinda non-trivial cogen to get it working (especially in case you want to do it in runtime).

Though there is no any kind of fundamental problem preventing us from implementing this. For example, [DIStage](https://github.com/pshirshov/izumi-r2) (disclaimer: I'm the author) complements traits (both in runtime and compiletime) allowing you not to write corresponding classes. You may look at the implementation [here](https://github.com/pshirshov/izumi-r2/blob/develop/distage/distage-proxy-cglib/src/main/scala/com/github/pshirshov/izumi/distage/provisioning/strategies/cglib/CgLibFactoryMethodInterceptor.scala).

So in fact you just need to intercept calls to trait's methods and forward them to corresponding implementations, this may be done with cglib or javassist, or you may generate relevant dispatchers with a macro.

We may implement this but what's your motivation behind?